# NaviCat Data synchronization crashes

Tags: postgresql, data-synchronization, navicat

I have a database that contains around 170 tables and some of those tables can contain up to 300 million rows! When I launch the data synchronization, it uses so much `RAM` that it ends up crashing my laptop. Do you know if there's any solution by which it does the comparison in a more intelligent way?
I don't understand why is it so inefficient.

Comment: I have the same problem, with a lot smaller database. This renders the sync option practically useless.